# How to display polling results through sql

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have got a useriInterface where I capture the radio button clicks and increment the counter in the database based on the selected value.

All this is working fine.

My question is that how can I display the polling Results percentage values?

This is my DB structure

```
CREATE TABLE `poll_results` (
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_date` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



Insert into poll_results (name,count,modified_date)values ('pollchoiceone' , 3 , now());
Insert into poll_results (name,count,modified_date)values ('pollchoicetwo' , 10 , now());
Insert into poll_results (name,count,modified_date)values ('pollchoicethree' , 7 , now());
Insert into poll_results (name,count,modified_date)values ('pollchoicefour' , 0 , now());
```

Is it possible to achieve that through a select query?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5e835/1

Comment: What would the desired result look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `cross join` a query from your table with a query that sums the entire number of votes, and then divide the two. E.g.:

```
SELECT     name, `count`, `count` / `total_count` * 100 AS percetnage
FROM       poll_results
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(`count`) AS `total_count` 
            FROM   poll_results) t
```

**[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5e835/4/0)**

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution using pre-built total_count table:

```
SELECT name, `count`, `count`/t.total_count * 100 AS percentage
FROM poll_results, (select sum(`count`) AS total_count from poll_results) t
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf291/16)